# How to solve $r''(\theta)r(\theta)^2 = \frac{a}{b}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This equation came up while solving a physics problem that asks to describe the path taken by a point mass acted on by some force. I made sure this equation really DOES come up. It's not an error I made.
I have no idea how to approach it.

I also tried wolfram alpha but it only gives plots of individual solutions not formulas

Comment: Write it as $r''(\theta) = \frac{c}{r(\theta)^2}$. Multiply by $r'(\theta)$ on both sides and integrate. The left hand side is $\frac{1}{2}[r'(\theta)^2]'$ which is easily integrated and the right hand side will be on the form $\int f(r){\rm d}r$ which you can also solve to get an equation on the form $r'(\theta) = g(r(\theta))$ which can be solved (you probably only will get a solution on implicit form $h(r(\theta)) = \theta$ as inverting $h$ will probably be hard).

Comment: I don't think that this equation has anything to do with the two-bodies problem, which I suspect. Because the derivative of $r$ must be taken on time, not angle, and even so, $\ddot r$ would not be the acceleration !

Comment: in fact this equation occurs after changing the independent variable from time to the angle and then making another change of the dependent variable. It's a bit complicated and I was too lazy to include the details. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$r''r'=\frac s{r^2}$$

integrates as

$$r'^2=c-\frac{2s}r,$$

which is separable.

$$\sqrt{\frac r{r-d}}r'=c$$

yields

$$\sqrt{r(r-d)}+d\log(\sqrt r+\sqrt{r-d})=c\,\theta+c'.$$